# Array value comes out to be wrong

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char *a1[10] = {"123","121"};
    int i =0;
    char *a=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        a=strcat(a1[i],"0000");
        printf("values %s",a);

    }
}
```

Output of this code comes out to be this:

```
$ ./a.exe values 1230000 values 0000000
```

but it should be:

```
$ ./a.exe values 1230000 values 1210000
```

Please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: you need to allocate a before writing to it.. also main is missing return statement

Comment: @amdixon  `return` is not a necessity .

Comment: it may not be required in c99+ but its just bad form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an array of array of char, but char *a1[10] is an array of pointers to char (tipically placed in read-only segments / string literals), trying to modify a string literal usually leads to a segmentation fault.

Change

```
char *a1[10] = {"123","121"};    /* Array of string literals (read only) */
```

to

```
char a1[][10] = {"123","121"};  /* Array of array of char (read - write) */
```